# Jasper Excel report exports a html content

Tags: java, excel, jasper-reports

I have two methods to export a pdf and an excel from jasper reports with primefaces. Exporting a pdf method works perfectly. But exporting excel exports a .xlxs though there are html codes inside the excel file and no any required data. The code is as follows.

**ChatListBean.java**

```
public void printExcel(){
    String reportPath = JsfUtil.getAbsolutePath("/resources/reports/chat.jasper");
    String subReportPath = JsfUtil.getAbsolutePath("/resources/reports");
    String realPath = JsfUtil.getAbsolutePath("");
    Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    params.put("realPath", realPath);
    params.put("SUBREPORT_DIR", subReportPath);
    // params.put("location", selectedLocation.getName());
    JRBeanCollectionDataSource beanCollectionDataSource = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(findChats);

    try {
        JasperReportUtil.toEXCEL(beanCollectionDataSource, reportPath, params, "Chat_History");

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ChatListBean.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

**JasperReportUtil.java**

```
public static void toEXCEL(JRBeanCollectionDataSource beanCollectionDataSource, String reportPath, Map<String, Object> params, String reportName) throws Exception{
    JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(reportPath, params, beanCollectionDataSource);
    HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse = (HttpServletResponse) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getResponse();
    httpServletResponse.addHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + reportName + ".xlsx");

    JRXlsExporter xlsExporter = new JRXlsExporter();
    xlsExporter.setExporterInput(new SimpleExporterInput(jasperPrint));
    xlsExporter.setExporterOutput(new SimpleOutputStreamExporterOutput(reportName));
    xlsExporter.exportReport();
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().responseComplete();

}
```

This is an exported Excel file

[image: This is Exported Excel file]
How do i fix this? I'm using following maven dependencies.

```
<groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
<artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
<version>6.5.1</version>
```

and

```
<groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
<artifactId>poi</artifactId>
<version>3.16</version>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done a mistake with *xlsExporter.setExporterOutput* method and working code is

```
public static void toEXCEL(JRBeanCollectionDataSource beanCollectionDataSource, String reportPath, Map<String, Object> params, String reportName) throws Exception{
    JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(reportPath, params, beanCollectionDataSource);
    HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse = (HttpServletResponse) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getResponse();
    httpServletResponse.addHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + reportName + ".xlsx");
    ServletOutputStream servletOutputStream = httpServletResponse.getOutputStream();
    JRXlsExporter xlsExporter = new JRXlsExporter();
    xlsExporter.setExporterInput(new SimpleExporterInput(jasperPrint));
    xlsExporter.setExporterOutput(new SimpleOutputStreamExporterOutput(servletOutputStream));
    xlsExporter.exportReport();

    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().responseComplete();
}
```